# How to capture video screen with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to create a function that captures the application screen in video, investigate and find this plugin:

https://github.com/sebible/cordova-videosnapshot

If someone has used it, they could share the way to install it or if they know of another plugin that fulfills this function or if the plugin should be programmed to complete the task.

Comment: Everything you need is written in the link you've posted. Go read it. Example how to implement it is at the bottom.

Comment: It says how to use but not how to install.

Install with cordova plugin or plugman. The javascript module will be injected automatically.

try with: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-videosnapshot --save

result: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-videosnapshot

Comment: Then put that in your question. We are not going to speculate what might be wrong. We won't investigate links. You tell us whats wrong, what you want to achieve etc. See [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to install `PlugMan`. If you already have npm installed, just run `npm install -g plugman` to install it. Once installed, try the following...

```
plugman install --platform android --project platforms\android --plugin cordova-videosnapshot
```

---

**Parameters**:

- --platform : The mobile platform you want to install the plugin for.
- --project : Path to the folder containing your cordova project.
- --plugin : The name of the plugin you're aiming to install.

You will need to download the Github repository.